# recursive query to find the root parent in oracle

Tags: sql, recursion

I am trying to figure out the root parent in a table with hierarchical data. The following example works as expected but I need to do something extra. I want to avoid the query to ignore null id1 and show the (root parent - 1) if the root parent is null.

```
with table_a ( id1, child_id ) as (
        select null, 1    from dual union all
       select 1, 2    from dual union all
       select 2, 3    from dual union all
       select 3, NULL from dual union all
       select 4, NULL from dual union all
       select 5, 6    from dual union all
       select 6, 7    from dual union all
       select 7, 8    from dual union all
       select 8, NULL from dual
     )
select     connect_by_root id1 as id, id1 as root_parent_id
from       table_a
where      connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by child_id = prior id1

order by id 1

This brings up the following data
4   4
6   5
7   5
8   5
5   5
3   null
null    null    
2   null
1   null

what I want is 

3   1
1   1
2   1
4   4
7   5
8   5
5   5
6   5

is it possible?

Thanks for the help
```

Comment: How exactly does it know to put in 1 for the columns with null?

Comment: It sure is. Use a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE you can do:

```
with table_a ( id1, child_id ) as (
        select null, 1    from dual union all
       select 1, 2    from dual union all
       select 2, 3    from dual union all
       select 3, NULL from dual union all
       select 4, NULL from dual union all
       select 5, 6    from dual union all
       select 6, 7    from dual union all
       select 7, 8    from dual union all
       select 8, NULL from dual
),
n (s, e) as (
  select id1 as s, child_id as e from table_a where id1 not in 
    (select child_id from table_a 
     where id1 is not null and child_id is not null)
  union all
  select n.s, a.child_id
  from n
  join table_a a on a.id1 = n.e
)
select
  coalesce(e, s) as c, s
from n
order by s
```

Result:

```
 C S 
 - - 
 3 1 
 1 1 
 2 1 
 4 4 
 5 5 
 7 5 
 8 5 
 6 5
```

As a side note, "Recursive CTEs" are more flexible than the old-school `CONNECT BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it works but it may be incorrect, as I do not quite understand the logic behind choosing 1 for this, looks arbitrary to me, not much like real data will be.
As Hogan has asked already, it would be helpful if you could perhaps provide an explanation or an expanded data set to test this hierarchy.

```
with table_a ( id1, child_id ) as (
       select null, 1    from dual union all
       select 1,    2    from dual union all
       select 2,    3    from dual union all
       select 3,    NULL from dual union all
       select 4,    NULL from dual union all
       select 5,    6    from dual union all
       select 6,    7    from dual union all
       select 7,    8    from dual union all
       select 8,    NULL from dual
     )
select     connect_by_root id1 as id, id1 as root_parent_id
from       table_a
where      connect_by_isleaf = 1 and connect_by_root id1 is not null
connect by nocycle child_id = prior nvl(id1, 1)
order by 2, 1;
```

Sample execution:

```
FSITJA@dbd01 2019-07-19 13:51:13> with table_a ( id1, child_id ) as (
  2         select null, 1    from dual union all
  3         select 1,    2    from dual union all
  4         select 2,    3    from dual union all
  5         select 3,    NULL from dual union all
  6         select 4,    NULL from dual union all
  7         select 5,    6    from dual union all
  8         select 6,    7    from dual union all
  9         select 7,    8    from dual union all
 10         select 8,    NULL from dual
 11       )
 12  select     connect_by_root id1 as id, id1 as root_parent_id
 13  from       table_a
 14  where      connect_by_isleaf = 1 and connect_by_root id1 is not null
 15  connect by nocycle child_id = prior nvl(id1, 1)
 16  order by 2, 1;

        ID ROOT_PARENT_ID
---------- --------------
         1              1
         2              1
         3              1
         4              4
         5              5
         6              5
         7              5
         8              5

8 rows selected.
```